# java hibernate exception on buildSessionFactory using session factory

Tags: hibernate

I have created a java application in netbeans which reads the csv file and inserts data to the SQL DB using hibernate ORM. Java application runs fine and inserts records to the DB when i run the application from the IDE. but if I compile the project into JAR file and run it in command prompt, then i get the following error. Any help is highly appreciated, Since i'm new to Java I couldnt figure out what is causing the issue.

here is the code for session

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

here is the exception that i got while running from command prompt

```
     Exception in thread "main" net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at com.genreproj.uploadpermission.RepPermissionUpload.ReadPermissionFile(RepPermissionUpload.java:108)
        at com.genreproj.uploadpermission.RepPermissionUpload.ProcessPermissionFile(RepPermissionUpload.java:72)
        at com.genreproj.processalluploads.ProcessAllUploads.main(ProcessAllUploads.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.genreproj.entity.SalesHistory$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$11666a3b"'s signer information does not match signer information
of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:943)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:657)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:785)
        ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I signed the jar file and executed it from command prompt, which caused the issue. If I run the jar file without signing, it works fine!